# how do I override Magento newsletter subscriber?

Tags: magento2, overrides

I have a hard time to work out the di.xml, I am trying to override a function of this file

```
vendor\Magento\module-newsltter\Model\Subscriber.php
```

anyone can tell me what should I do? **I think I have problem with create the di.xml and module.xml files**

I created below files:

```
app/code/ABC/NewsletterApi/Model/Subscriber.php
app/code/ABC/NewsletterApi/etc/di.xml
app/code/ABC/NewsletterApi/etc/module.xml
app/code/ABC/NewsletterApi/registration.php
```

app/code/ABC/NewsletterApi/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" type="ABC\NewsletterApi\Model\Subscriber" />
</config>
```

app/code/ABC/NewsletterApi/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ABC_NewsletterApi" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Subscriber.php

```
public function unsubscribe()
{
    if ($this->hasCheckCode() && $this->getCode() != $this->getCheckCode()) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('This is an invalid subscription confirmation code.')
        );
    }

    if ($this->getSubscriberStatus() != self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED) {
        $this->setSubscriberStatus(self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED)->save();
        $this->sendUnsubscriptionEmail();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check config.php that your module enabled
2. Did you add `class Subscriber extends Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber` ?
3. Please add sequence to your module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ABC_NewsletterApi" setup_version="1.0.0">
         <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Newsletter" /> 
        </sequence>
    <module>
</config>
```

Comment: after I add the sequence, it has error

Comment: I removed the "module" line, now its back to normal, however the override seems not taking place, the module was enabled, I did di compile, setup upgrade and flush the cache as well.